# SQL UPDATE, having problems updating my candidate table

Tags: mysql

iam trying to update rows but iam receiving error / or only the first record is filled in all

```
UPDATE candidate 
SET Cand_phone = '8698504', Cand_email = 'TomH@navy.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C100';
SET Cand_phone = '8394442', Cand_email = 'AlanBarry@yahoo.com'WHERE Cand_Num = 'C101';
SET Cand_phone = '8765892', Cand_email = 'CopperWin@fiji.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C102';
SET Cand_phone = '9003452', Cand_email = 'Stark@gmail.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C103';
SET Cand_phone = '7888231', Cand_email = 'HughJack@mail.com'WHERE Cand_Num = 'C104';
SET Cand_phone = '8900043', Cand_email = 'JeanGrey@usp.com.fj'WHERE Cand_Num = 'C105';
SET Cand_phone = '8733020', Cand_email = 'Furry@yahoo.com'WHERE Cand_Num = 'C106';
SET Cand_phone = '9008702', Cand_email = 'Blaze@gmail.com'WHERE Cand_Num = 'C107';
SET Cand_phone = '9034504', Cand_email = 'Banner@yahoo.com'WHERE Cand_Num = 'C108';
SET Cand_phone = '9088767', Cand_email = 'Clint@gmail.com'WHERE Cand_Num = 'C1009';
```

Comment: Only 1st query is correct. In all another UPDATE clause is lost.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this questions appears to be a homework.

Comment: it's not a homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to this:

```
UPDATE candidate SET Cand_phone = '8698504', Cand_email = 'TomH@navy.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C100';
UPDATE candidate SET Cand_phone = '8394442', Cand_email = 'AlanBarry@yahoo.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C101';
UPDATE candidate SET Cand_phone = '8765892', Cand_email = 'CopperWin@fiji.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C102';
UPDATE candidate SET Cand_phone = '9003452', Cand_email = 'Stark@gmail.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C103';
UPDATE candidate SET Cand_phone = '7888231', Cand_email = 'HughJack@mail.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C104';
UPDATE candidate SET Cand_phone = '8900043', Cand_email = 'JeanGrey@usp.com.fj' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C105';
UPDATE candidate SET Cand_phone = '8733020', Cand_email = 'Furry@yahoo.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C106';
UPDATE candidate SET Cand_phone = '9008702', Cand_email = 'Blaze@gmail.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C107';
UPDATE candidate SET Cand_phone = '9034504', Cand_email = 'Banner@yahoo.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C108';
UPDATE candidate SET Cand_phone = '9088767', Cand_email = 'Clint@gmail.com' WHERE Cand_Num = 'C1009';
```

In your update statement, you can update multiple fields. Since you have different where clause for each update, create multiple multiple update statements.

Comment: @SaurabNandDamzus   You are welcome to put closure to your question by accept it as an answer. There should be check mark by the answer that you can click.